# Increasing number's value after each "load"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building simple 'lazyload' for my page. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function scrollBottom() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
            var count = 1;
            var link = 2;
            var biglink = $('div.nav a').attr('href');
            var biglink = biglink.split('/page/');
                $('div.nav').before('<div class="lazy"></div>');

                $('div.lazy').load(biglink[0] + '/page/' + link + ' div.cnt > * ', function() {
                    link = parseInt(link.value++);
                });
        }
    });
}
```

(please note that this code is very WIP so many variables aren't needed etc.).

My problem is, `link` value is always `2`. It never gets higher. What can I do?

Comment: What is `link` even? If it is a numeric string, it does not have a `value` property. Just do `link++`.

Comment: `link` is numeric. `link++` doesn't work, tried before.

Comment: You seem to be defining `link` multiple times, each time it is a different kind of value. Then you want to increment it? your code isn't making any sense.

Comment: Why did you think `link.value` should work? I recommend to read [this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to learn how to debug JS, set breakpoints and inspect the variables.

Comment: Each new line of `link` is replacing old value. Making `link1, link2, link3` variables would be messy. Please try to read the code once more.

Comment: @FelixKling it's simply numeric value. I try to simply put `link = 2` in my code and then run it, but it was `2` all the time.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Right, but how do you want to increment it? It's always going to be `link[5]` (which is a string), you can't increment it because you're redefining it every time.

Comment: Since we don't know the HTML, we don't know what `$('div.nav a')` will select and we don't know what `.load(biglink[0] + '/page/' + link + ' div.cnt > * '` will load... there is not enough information to help you, you have to debug the code yourself or create a proper http://jsfiddle.net demo. And regarding the numeric values: As I said, neither numbers nor strings have a `value` property.

Comment: Okay, I've reedited my question with just changing `link` to static value. Problem still exists.

Comment: Well, whenever the event handler is called, you are initializing `link` with `2`... the modification you do at the end is just "lost". If you want the value to persist between handler calls you have to define the variable outside of the handler.

Comment: @FelixKling contents of `load` aren't important. Let's say it's a collection of `article` elements.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski You're still redefining `link` every time the window scrolls. Every time that event happens, `link` will be defined as `2`

Comment: Thanks guys, I did mved `link` before scroll and it works. But now it is raising very weird - 2, 3, 5, 8, 12

Comment: @TomekBuszewski are you still using `link = parseInt(link.value++);`? it should be `link++`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
link = parseInt(link.value);
link++;
```